# How to null self-referencing fk on delete of parent in EF5 - Code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, entity-framework-5, cascading-deletes

I have a Question Entity. My entity contains a CreatedFrom of type Question that contains a reference to the question it was created from. So a self reference.

Now I use the CreatedFrom to update the original question as long as it's around. But the user can remove the original question, leaving my question "orphaned". This however is perfectly okay as it's the design of the system.

Now I added this line to my DbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Question>().HasOptional(x => x.CreatedFrom);
```

But it still refuses to let me delete the "parent" saying relation is in the way.

What I want is to be able to delete the parent, and when I do the CreatedFrom should be nulled on any Question that has the CreatedFrom set to the ID of the now deleted question.

Comment: Is your CreatedFromId nullable property?

Comment: The HasOptional should make it nullable, and a quick peek in the db tells me that it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must load the child questions into the context. If you delete the parent EF should set the reference `CreatedFrom` for all attached children to `null` and save this as an UPDATE to the database:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var parentQuestion = context.Questions
        .SingleOrDefault(q => q.Id == someId);

    if (parentQuestion != null)
    {
        context.Questions
            .Where(q => q.CreatedFrom.Id == someId)
            .Load();

        context.Questions.Remove(parentQuestion);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

If you have a `ChildQuestions` collection property in `Question` you can simplify this by adding `Include(q => q.ChildQuestions)` to the query for the `parentQuestion` and remove the query that loads the children explicitly.

Comment: Great answer, but one question remains. The questions (of the parent kind) belongs to a Question group. And right now I have this: modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionSet>().HasMany(x => x.Questions).WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);  That will stop working then too, right. So on delete on a Question group/set I must do the same logic.

Comment: @RickardLiljeberg: Yes, you probably have to load the questions of a set and their child questions as well in order to delete a set.